# Use CSS grid as a calendar

Tags: css, css-grid

After researching on the alternatives available to draw an HTML calendar in a page, I ended up that the easiest way to do it, with by far the less CSS and HTML markup possible is the CSS grid layout. The problem is I've never used a grid before and I don't know how to achieve the 100% of what I need. So, I came up with the following, that is 80% of it...

```css
.calendar {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.day {
  padding: 5px 30px 30px 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #0074d9;
}

.weekday {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
    background-color: #333;
}

span {display:block;border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #fff;margin-bottom: 4px;}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="weekday">Mon</div>
  <div class="weekday">Tue</div>
  <div class="weekday">Wed</div>
  <div class="weekday">Thu</div>
  <div class="weekday">Fri</div>
  <div class="weekday">Sat</div>
  <div class="weekday">Sun</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="day">1</div>
  <div class="day">2</div>
  <div class="day">3</div>
  <div class="day">4</div>
  <div class="day">5</div>
  <div class="day">6</div>
  <div class="day">7</div>
  <div class="day">8</div>
  <div class="day">9</div>
  <div class="day">10</div>
  <div class="day">11</div>
  <div class="day">12</div>
  <div class="day">13</div>
  <div class="day">14<span>11:00</span><span>12:00</span><span>13:00</span><span>14:00</span></div>
  <div class="day">15</div>
  <div class="day">16</div>
  <div class="day">17</div>
  <div class="day">18</div>
  <div class="day">19</div>
  <div class="day">20</div>
  <div class="day">21</div>
  <div class="day">22</div>
  <div class="day">23</div>
  <div class="day">24</div>
  <div class="day">25</div>
  <div class="day">26</div>
  <div class="day">27</div>
  <div class="day">28</div>
  <div class="day">29</div>
  <div class="day">30</div>
  <div class="day">31</div>
</div>
```

The rest 20% is a first line (above the weekdays, using the same 5px gap) that would be a Month Year, like October 2022, which should obviously span across all 7 columns of the first row, and then a way to display some hours within some days, like 12:00, then below it something like 13:00, then 14:00 (they shouldn't be more than 5-6 times)... And maybe those times could each come in a nice rectangular border with rounded corners... Something like each time in a different span, where spans would stack up one onto the other, etc... All this I'm describing, is perfectly doable with CSS in general, but putting them in a cell of a grid layout gives me a hard time so far...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit: In the meantime I got a little closer to what I want, but it's still not looking perfect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achive this "The rest 20% is a first line (above the weekdays, using the same 5px gap) that would be a Month Year, like October 2022"

do this

```
<div class="calendar">

 <div class="month-year">October 2022</div>

  <div class="weekday">Mon</div>
  <div class="weekday">Tue</div>
  <div class="weekday">Wed</div>
  <div class="weekday">Thu</div>
  <div class="weekday">Fri</div>
  <div class="weekday">Sat</div>
  <div class="weekday">Sun</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  .
  .
  .
```

css

```
.month-year{
   grid-column: 1 / 8;
}
```

it will span this div from first column to last column